# Doctrine ArrayCollection->first() returns boolean

Tags: php, doctrine, arraycollection

Hey using Doctrine ORM with attribute GeoData

```php
    /**
     * @var GeoData[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\GeoData", inversedBy="addresses", cascade="persist", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users__addresses_geodata")
     */
    protected $geoData;
```

and with a special getter to acquire first element of GeoData

```php
    public function getMostLocalGeoDatum(): ?GeoData
    {
        if (null == $this->geoData && $this->geoData->isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        /** @var GeoData $localeGeoDatum */
        $localeGeoDatum = $this->geoData->first();

        return $localeGeoDatum;
    }
```

but everytime I use this getter, I get a error:

```
TypeError: Return value of ACME\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Address::getMostLocalGeoDatum() must be an instance of ACME\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\GeoData or null, boolean returned
```

Any clue what might be wrong? According to Doctrine ArrayCollection documentation, first() should return first element of ArrayCollection.

Comment: Is this line `if (null == $this->geoData && $this->geoData->isEmpty())` correct? First you verify that geoData is null, and then if its empty (but only if geoData is null). This should generate an unexpected behaviour, i believe
I guess that `if (is_null($this->geoData) || ($this->geoData->isEmpty())` works better... maybe

Comment: `first()` internally uses [`reset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset), which returns `false` when the array is empty. So fixing your condition like Gowire suggested should clear this up.

Comment: If you take a look at the true signature of [`first`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/2.0.x/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.php#L164), you'll see it is marked as returning a result or false.

Comment: The best, thank you for clear correction!

Comment: Updated link for first() showing it returns false on empty collection: https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/2.1.x/src/ReadableCollection.php#L88

Answer (score 1):

The first `if` should not be `and`, instead it should be an `or` condition.